# Silverstripe Image Upload is changing name

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am uploading an image and while storing the image, I am setting the Filename like 'assets/Uploads/54f092af271b9.png' but after saving, the Filename fields loses some part. It becomes 'assets/54f092af271b9.png' losing the "Uploads/" directory altogether. Is it supposed to happen?

Here's the codes:

```
            <?php 
            $img = new Image();
            $baseName = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
            $fileName = 'assets/Uploads/' . $baseName;

            var_dump($fileName);

            $img->Name = $baseName;
            $img->Filename = $fileName;
            $img->OwnerID = ($memberID = Member::currentUserID()) ? $memberID : 0;
            $img->write();


            var_dump($img->Filename); exit;
```

Output is:

assets/Uploads/54f092af271b9.png
assets/54f092af271b9.png'

Any ideas?

Comment: I didn't have any trouble what is in your write function? are you resetting the Filename?

Comment: It's built in Silverstripe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to replicate the issue with the code you provided. After a bit of digging around, here is what I found.

It all starts in the [`onAfterWrite`](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/aec84303956d31f8db9f288b4aa5223f2de4dda4/filesystem/File.php#L493-L501) function in [`File`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-File.html) class (which [`Image`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Image.html) extends). Fired after you called `write` (obviously), this calls `updateFilesystem` where [this line](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/aec84303956d31f8db9f288b4aa5223f2de4dda4/filesystem/File.php#L518-L519) sets the `Filename` property with the result of the [`getRelativePath`](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/aec84303956d31f8db9f288b4aa5223f2de4dda4/filesystem/File.php#L701-L720) function call.

At the time of writing, `getRelativePath` looks like this:

```
public function getRelativePath() {
    if($this->ParentID) {
        // Don't use the cache, the parent has just been changed
        $p = DataObject::get_by_id('Folder', $this->ParentID, false);
        if($p && $p->exists()) return $p->getRelativePath() . $this->getField("Name");
        else return ASSETS_DIR . "/" . $this->getField("Name");
    } else if($this->getField("Name")) {
        return ASSETS_DIR . "/" . $this->getField("Name");
    } else {
        return ASSETS_DIR;
    }
}
```

Looking at that code, the issue you have comes from `ParentID` not being set on your record when you wrote it to the DB so the second condition is run instead returning the result of `ASSETS_DIR . "/" . $this->getField("Name")`.

So that is the problem addressed, now for a solution. Silverstripe wants a parent folder, you've just got to give it one.

Fortunately there is a great little function on the [`Folder`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Folder.html) class called [`find_or_make`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Folder.html#_find_or_make) which does what the name says, either finds the folder record in the filesystem and DB or it will generate it for you.

*Note: In my own testing, while I had an "Uploads" folder, I did not have a corresponding DB record so this function wrote that for me an returned the result.*

I then used the result to give the image I was writing to the DB a `ParentID` and it made the second `var_dump` return the same value as the first.

This is all you need to add to your code before calling `write`:

```
$parentFolder = Folder::find_or_make('Uploads');
$img->setParentID($parentFolder->ID);
```