# SilverStripe Image DataObject not available after creation

Tags: silverstripe

I have this code that creates a new Image based on a new file added to the filesystem but not yet in the DB:

```
$image = Image::create();
$image->Filename = 'assets/Art/e3434cc7-d348-491a-9dc8-325af3d9086d.jpg';
$image->write();

$images = Image::get();
$image = $images->last();

$vd = new ViewableData();
$ad = new ArrayData(array(
   'Image' => $image
));
$strHTML = $vd->customise($ad)->renderWith('Art');
```

**Art.ss** contains only `$Image.SetWidth(100)`

Ignoring the fact the query doesn't look up by ID or whatever... why is the image only rendered into `$strHTML` if I retrieve the image from the DB after creating? If I delete the code below, `$strHTML` is empty:

```
$images = Image::get();
$image = $images->last();
```

Comment: what does `var_dump($image);` or `$Image.Debug` (in your template) give you? An Image object? Does the image file exist? Is assets/Art/ writeable to the webserver? have you flushed?

Comment: `var_dump($image)` after `$image->write()` spits out an Image object, but for some reason the Filename property is `assets/e3434cc7-d348-491a-9dc8-325af3d9086d.jpg` not `assets/Art/e3434cc7-d348-491a-9dc8-325af3d9086d.jpg` as it is when retrieved from the DB. There are some other differences: https://www.diffnow.com/?report=scxft. Left document is one after write, right document is one created straight after and then retrieved from the DB.

Comment: these are two different images, as they have a different IDs set, see $record array...
How is the file copied to assets? And i wonder why another file is created...

Comment: I just ran the script above twice, so it created two images. The first time I var_dump()'d after `$image->write();`, the second after `$image = $images->last();`.

Comment: Looks to be a [similar issue as another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28769308/1676444). Basically like @Jono mentioned, there is no `ParentID` set for the record, when you call write, it calls `getRelativePath` which fails to lookup the parent folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a setter available so using that alone may help, but you also may need to assign the ID of the parent folder to the object:

```
$pFolder = Folder::find_or_make('Art');
if ($pFolder) {
    $image->setParentID($pFolder->ID);
    $image->setFilename('assets/Art/e3434cc7-d348-491a-9dc8-325af3d9086d.jpg');
}
```